# What is this? Fresh Kale looks to have small sprouting seeds, although looks similar to insect eggs

Tags: food-identification, kale

Picked up from farmer's market yesterday. Not sure if organic.

No smell. Slimey texture. Strong grip. A few have started to sprout.

About 4 on this one leaf. Other leafs have none.

[image: Fresh Kale with unknown seeds growing]

Any idea what they could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the nice picture! They don't look like insect eggs to me. The one at the bottom of the photo, with the little groove/stripe down the middle & the sprout, looks like a seed, not of kale, but maybe some kind of grain. The one nearer the top, by your thumb, not sure. Maybe just strays from the field or the back of the truck. Wash your kale; I'm sure it's fine.

Comment: Thank you Lorel for your answer. I agree that the two unidentified objects were different. After a good washing, I found a [cabbage worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbage_worm) clinging to the sink drain. Luckily not harmful, just means that the produce is fresh. Chopped and cooked - the kale that is, the worm I decided wouldn't be too delicious.